# Ideals of the quadratic integer ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, normed-spaces, euclidean-domain, quadratic-integer-rings

[image: Example from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra Text]

Can someone please explain the contradiction when we take $a^2 + 5b^2$ to be equal to $1$.

After multiplying both sides by $2 - \sqrt{-5}$ and factoring at a $3$ I get $$3\left[\left(2-\sqrt{-5} \right) \gamma + 3\delta \right] = 2-\sqrt{-5}$$ Why does this imply $2-\sqrt{-5}$ is a multiple of $3$ and why is that a contradiction?

Comment: Note $12-9 \in (3,2+\sqrt{-5})(3,2-\sqrt{-5})$. It says if $(3,2+\sqrt{-5}) = (a+b \sqrt{-5})$ then $(3) = (3,2+\sqrt{-5})(3,2-\sqrt{-5})  = (a+b \sqrt{-5})(a-b \sqrt{-5}) = (a^2+5 b^2)$ which is clearly impossible for $a,b$ integers.

Comment: I had a typo in my question, my apologies. My focus is on the third part of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It is a multiple of $3$ since you can write it as $3$ times another element of the ring, specifically you wrote it is $3 \times (\left(2-\sqrt{-5} \right) \gamma + 3\delta)$ and $\left(2-\sqrt{-5} \right) \gamma + 3\delta$ is an element of the ring.

This is a contradiction because for any inetegrs $c,d$ you have that $3(c+d \sqrt{-5})$ is $3c + 3d \sqrt{-5}$ and as the representation in the form $x + y \sqrt{-5}$ with $x,y$ integers is unique it would follow that $3$ divides $2$ and $-1$ (as integers), which it does not.